# Does "fu" mean weed?

Tags: meaning, slang

Google translated "[fu](https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/fu)" as "weed" or "marijuana". However, dictionaries such as [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fu) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=fu) don't have this definition. Does "fu" really mean "weed"?

Comment: What is the context? "fu" has many slang meanings but it depends on how it's being used.

Comment: fu can means weed?

Comment: I've never heard it used that way. Do you mean marijuana or invasive plants?

Comment: yes, I mean marijuana. http://i.imgur.com/09QmB1g.png

Comment: This question could probably be reopened by editing to link to a dictionary that does not have this word (and none of them seem to have it, so you have plenty of choices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently slang in the drug-using community. See the [Drug Slang Dictionary](https://www.noslang.com/drugs/dictionary/f/):

> fu - Marijuana

Comment: I wonder how that's pronounced.

Comment: Neither of the references I found had a pronunciation guide.

Answer (score 2):

One particularly interesting source that verifies that "fu" is slang for marijuana is [this PDF containing a list of drug terms](https://vva.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/street-terms.pdf) from the [Office of National Drug Control Policy](https://www.whitehouse.gov/ondcp/) (a US agency).

Another source, the [Marijuana Dictionary](http://www.marijuanadictionary.com/words/f-words/) (which also appears to sell marijuana) elaborates a little on its definition:

> Fu is an unkind marijuana term.

Answer (score -1):

Note that "fu" is often uses as a suffix of sorts denote skill.  Someone who can use Google very effectively is said to have good "Google-fu", eg.

Answer (score -4):

'fu' is not slang...
Online, people use 'fu' to represent 'f*ck you'.

Maybe a close group of friends use 'fu' as code, in order to be secretive of their drug use. In this sense it does not qualify as slang.

Comment: The abbreviation _FU_ does not appear to be related to this word. And if a close group of friends did use a word as code to hide their drug use, that would be a cant which absolutely qualifies as slang within that group.